# JNI with gradle

Tags: c, gradle, java-native-interface

How to build shared library with gradle?

my project tree

> core/c/{*.c, *.h}
>
> core/c/include/{jni, lib}

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'c'

def JNI_INCLUDE_DIR = this.properties['jni.include.dir']

model {
        components {
                bridge(NativeLibrarySpec) {
                        sources.c.source {
                                srcDir 'core/c'
                                include '**/*.c'
                        }
                        sources.c.exportedHeaders {
                                srcDir 'core/c/include'
                        }
                        buildTypes {
                                debug
                                release
                        }
                }
        }
toolChains {
                gcc(Gcc) {
                        if(System.properties['os.name'].equals("Mac OS X")) {
                                cCompiler.withArguments {
                                        args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR
                                        args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR + "/darwin"
                                        args << "-std=gnu11"
                                        args << "-g"
                                }
                        } else {
                                cCompiler.withArguments {
                                        args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR
                                        args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR + "/linux"
                                        args << "-std=gnu11"
                                        args << "-g"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Error

> Exception thrown while executing model rule: toolChains { ... } @ build.gradle line 23, column 2
> Could not get unknown property 'cCompiler' for Tool chain 'gcc' (GNU GCC) of type org.gradle.nativeplatform.toolchain.internal.gcc.GccToolChain.

Answer (score 0):

[The `Gcc` class](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/toolchain/Gcc.html) has no property `cCompiler` which is why you get the error. `cCompiler` is instead a property of [`GccPlatformToolchain`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/toolchain/GccPlatformToolChain.html). `Gcc` has one or more instances of platform toolchains. If you want to apply your flags to each platform within the `Gcc` toolchain, you can use `eachPlatform`, for example:

```
toolChains {
    gcc(Gcc) {
        eachPlatform {
            if(System.properties['os.name'].equals("Mac OS X")) {
                cCompiler.withArguments {
                    args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR
                    args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR + "/darwin"
                    args << "-std=gnu11"
                    args << "-g"
                }
            } else {
                cCompiler.withArguments {
                    args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR
                    args << "-I" + JNI_INCLUDE_DIR + "/linux"
                    args << "-std=gnu11"
                    args << "-g"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe you can also define custom platforms for a given operating system/architecture and then reference those inside the Gcc block, rather than using an if statement, which might be cleaner and more idiomatic.